# Jenkins - How to clean / move files under 'builds' directory

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I am using Jenkins with Pipeline script. At the end of the script I want to delete/move some contents of `Jenkins\jobs\MyMultiBranch\branches\master\builds` (i.e. some logs and build.xml)

How can it be done using Pipeline?
I tried this;

```
bat "del /F \"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Jenkins\\jobs\\MyMultiBranch\\branches\\master\\builds\\%BUILD_NUMBER%\\build.xml\""
```

but it's not working, the files are still there. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does make sense that Jenkins would not be able to delete its own working directory.
I guess what you could do is first save artifacts you want to save as Daniel mentionned and then trigger a second job (say `delete-job`) that will be responsible for cleaning your `job A` workspace. It would look like this :

```java
// First save out anything you want
archiveArtifacts artifacts: '**/saveme.log'

// At the very end of your pipeline, call delete-job with the path you want to delete as a build parameter
build job: 'delete-job', quietPeriod: 5, wait: false, parameters: [[$class: 'StringParameterValue', name: 'folderToDelete', value: "${pathToFolderToDelete}"]]
```

The quiet period should be enough for the delete-job to be able to delete your `job A` folder.

`delete-job` would simply look like that :

```java
node() {
  bat "del /F '${pathToFolderToDelete}'"
}
```

Where `pathToFolderToDelete` is a variable automatically infered by Jenkins based on the job parameters.

Comment: yep, chained jobs is a feasable solution as we know we cannot release lock until job is done. I'll try this and return.

Comment: This one answered the question (unlike mine).  +1 :)

Comment: It worked very well. Thanks to both of you. One last question; One line you gave didnt work so I had to change it as following:
`bat "del /F \"${pathToFolderToDelete}\""`
Are you using something like cygpath plugin? Did you test it working?

Comment: I didn't test it, my Jenkins is on a Debian machine so I would use sh for this purpose... Sorry about that, I'm not too familiar with bat.

Comment: No problem mate, I was just curious if I've missed something. I made an edit proposal.