# Is there a way to delete archived items from Jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is there an easy way to delete archived items in jenkins using a jenkinsfile?  The only google hits I've found talk about deleting them manually which is no good for what I want...

Comment: may be this can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39079212/jenkins-how-to-clean-move-files-under-builds-directory

Answer (score 0):

In  Jenkins Manage jenkins > Script console 
   Just Paste below code and run

```
import hudson.model.*
// For each project
for(item in Hudson.instance.items) {
  // check that job is not building
  if(!item.isBuilding()) {
    println("Wiping out workspace of job "+item.name)
    item.doDoWipeOutWorkspace()
  }
  else {
    println("Skipping job "+item.name+", currently building")
  }
}
```

Comment: That wipes out workspaces. That is different from deleting archived artifacts.